# Display bundle product's child item's images like normal product images

Tags: magento-1, bundle, package

Is there a way to show bundle product's child item's product images as the images of the main bundle product?

We are using bundle products to sell products as product packages or kits (with small hacks to template to prevent customers from seeing the normal bundle options). So we need to display the bundle item's images like normal product images below the main product image list. Is this possible somehow?

UPDATE:

Here is the media.phtml file's code from my template. Could the bundle items' images be added in here somehow?

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>


<p class="product-image">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(600,600); ?>"  rel="<?php echo implode($config, ',');?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>" id="zoom1" class="cloud-zoom">    
        <?php
        echo '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(292,320).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'"/>';            
        ?>
        </a>

    <?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
     <a id="zoom-btn" class="lightbox-group zoom-btn-small" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(600,600); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Zoom'); ?></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
</p>


<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>

<div class="more-views additional-carousel">

    <?php 
            $sliderFor = 4;
            $productCount = count($this->getGalleryImages());
    ?>  

    <?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor): ?>
        <div class="customNavigation">
            <a class="btn prev">&nbsp;</a>
            <a class="btn next">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>  
    <?php endif; ?> 

        <div id="additional-carousel" class="<?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>product-carousel<?php }else{?>products-grid<?php }?>">

        <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <div class="slider-item">
                <div class="product-block"> 

                <a href='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(600,600);?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery lightbox-group' title='<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(292,320);?>' ">

                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />

                </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

    <span class="additional_default_width" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {

            $(".lightbox-group").colorbox({
                rel:        'lightbox-group',
                opacity:    0.5,
                speed:      300
            });
            $(".cloud-zoom-gallery").first().removeClass("cboxElement");
            $(".cloud-zoom-gallery").click(function() {
                $("#zoom-btn").attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
                $("#zoom-btn").attr('title', $(this).attr('title'));

                $(".cloud-zoom-gallery").each(function() {
                        $(this).addClass("cboxElement");
                    });
                $(this).removeClass("cboxElement");
            });

        });

        jQuery(function($) {
        var t; $(window).resize(function() { clearTimeout(t); t = setTimeout(function() { $(".cloud-zoom-gallery").first().click(); }, 200); });
        });

    </script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi webninja - did you manage to get this sorted or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Hi Jon. No this is not yet sorted.

Comment: Did you manage to get the images of the products? Could you tell me how you did it and what you have archived?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140918)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140918)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140918)

Answer (score 1):

For each bundle product you could load all the child ids, loop through the resultant set, pulling out the images.

You could get a list of the child ids and pull out the images that way

```
$parentId = 1234; //or whatever the bundle product is
$childIds =   Mage::getResourceSingleton("bundle/selection")->getChildrenIds($parentId,true);
$childImagesArray = array();
foreach($childIds as $cids){ 
    foreach($cids as $cid){ //yer an awkward array in an array here
        $childProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($cid);
        echo "<br/>".$childProduct->getName();
        $childProductImage = $childProduct->getImage(); // OR getSmallImage()  OR getThumbnail();
        var_dump($childProductImage); //see what you get out here
        //now add your data to an array $childImagesArray[] = ....  or do something else with your results.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this works for you, I don't have any bundles active to fully test this at the moment.

Comment: Being a no programmer at all I require more assistance. I need help on the first line already. How do I get the parentID automatically?

Comment: hmm, rather depends on the context.  Could you post the code of the page you are using?

Comment: If your .phtml page has something like

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

then you can get the id of the product like so:  <?php $_product->getId(); ?>

Comment: Or <?php $_product->getData("id"); ?>    Does the same thing in the end

Comment: hi bro it give path like /J/O/imgname.png how to get full path

Comment: One way is to put this at the front: 
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(‘media’)."catalog/product"; ?>